# Trespass Law in Illinois

Tags: illinois, trespassing

Can you be trespassed by a municipality over a privately owned property only by verbal warning or does notice have to be given for the trespass to be deemed legal ? Under the law what actually constitues tresspass that's enforceable ?

Comment: Can you clarify: is the municipality the owner of the property, or is the municipality acting on behalf of the owner?

Answer (score 2):

### Verbal warning is notice

If the owner of a property demands you to leave, that is all the notice they need to give: by stating that you are not or are no longer allowed to be there, you are on notice that staying is trespassing.